# How to fix MTKView random fill color when rendering a new image

Tags: swift, metal, core-image

I'm working on a photo editor and I just switched from a *UIImageView* to an *MTKView* for performance reasons. It works great except for some reason on some images there is a red box. The image size changes and the red box gets bigger when displaying a new image.

*I am using Mac Catalyst on this*

This is my *MTKView* code

```swift
    public let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    public lazy var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue = {
        [unowned self] in

        if self.device == nil {
            self.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        }

        return self.device!.makeCommandQueue()!
        }()

    public lazy var ciContext: CIContext = {
        [unowned self] in

        if self.device == nil {
            self.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        }

        let context = CIContext(mtlDevice: self.device!, options: [CIContextOption.highQualityDownsample: true, CIContextOption.priorityRequestLow: false])

        return context
        }()

    public override init(frame frameRect: CGRect, device: MTLDevice? = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect,
                   device: device ?? MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice())

        if super.device == nil
        {
            fatalError("Device doesn't support Metal")
        }

        self.framebufferOnly = false
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.framebufferOnly = false

        self.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    }

    /// The image to display
    public var image: CIImage?
    {
        didSet
        {

            renderImage()
        }
    }

    public var orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation? {
        didSet {

            renderImage()
        }
    }

    func renderImage()
    {

        guard var
            image = self.image,
            let targetTexture = self.currentDrawable?.texture else
        {
            print("No texture/image")
            return
        }

        self.drawableSize = image.extent.size

        if let orientation = orientation {
            image = image.oriented(orientation)
        }

        let commandBuffer = self.commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()

        let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.drawableSize)

        let originX = image.extent.origin.x
        let originY = image.extent.origin.y

        let scaleX = self.drawableSize.width / image.extent.width
        let scaleY = self.drawableSize.height / image.extent.height
        let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)

        let scaledImage = image
            .transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: -originX, y: -originY))
            .transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))

        self.ciContext.render(scaledImage,
                              to: targetTexture,
                              commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                              bounds: bounds,
                              colorSpace: self.colorSpace)

        commandBuffer?.present(self.currentDrawable!)

        commandBuffer?.commit()

        self.draw()

        self.releaseDrawables()
    }
```

Comment: You say you are using Catalyst, which implies iPadOS, correct? Are you having the same issue on an iPad?

Comment: @dfd No, on iPad it just has the weird change in size when updating the image, but there is no red box.

Comment: Without anything more, this sounds like a bug on Apple's end. At least this red box. Tomorrow I'll try your posted code on both 13.1 and 13.2. I'll let you know.

Comment: Could you maybe post an image of the red box?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel [Displayed when setting the image originally](https://i.imgur.com/a1wpFjY.png)

Comment: It looks like the red is the content of the view's drawable texture before you render into it. And since your image doesn't fit the whole view, some part of the original content is still visible. Could you maybe try to scale to aspect-fill (instead of fit) by changing the scale like this: `let scale = max(scaleX, scaleY)`?